# iterator for strings in array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, iterator

i have the following situation

```
typedef std::array<std::array<string,9>,9>candidates;
std::vector<candidates>cand;
```

i need to traverse the strings in depths of recursion and want them unaltered even with re-sizing. how do i do it? the iterators i was using previously get invalidated on re-sizing i want a way around.. here's the previous attempt.

```
for(itr[d] = cand[d][i][j].begin(); itr[d] !=cand[d][i][j].end(); ++itr[d])
   {
    //if condition met - proceed to recursive call

    //else reset (using ppp and push) and proceed to next element of string 
   }
```

Comment: What is the error message you get? Can you give a minimal test case? My compiler(g++4.5.2) didn't complaint with it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
func(*(itr[d]));
```

The dereference operator takes precedence over the indexing operator.